# Select order by random() Query not working in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using a query in my repository and i'm trying to select 10 random questions from a table. but I get this error
 *ASC or DESC expected got '('* 
and i have no idea why

```
@Query ( value = "select q from Question q where q.chapitre_id=:id order by 
random() limit 10", nativeQuery = true)
List<Question> findQuestionsByChapitre(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Comment: Try rand() instead of random()

Comment: that didnt work either

Comment: You shouldn't use `limit 10` here as few databases like `Oracle` doesn't support though many support. I would recommend you to try with `Page` and `Pageable` interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me :

```
    @Query ( value = "select * from  question q where q.chapitre_id=:id order 
    by rand() limit 10", nativeQuery = true)
    Question[] findQuestionsByChapitre(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ordering by 1, 2, 3 or whatever number means ordering by the column in the corresponding position; if you only select one column (`q` in your case) you will be able to order only by that (it may work in older versions though).

Then, the correct syntax for ordering by a casual value is `order by rand()`